# Is it required to change version code and version name every time when we upload the android app for internal testing?

Tags: android, version

I would like to upload the Android app for internal testing.

Is it required to change the version code and version name every time I upload the app for internal testing only?

I think it does not make sense for the play store version code as the app is in still for internal testing.

If any other way I can do Please give some suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number needs to change each time.  It needs to be monotonically increasing, or the upgrade path doesn't work properly (when the Play Store checks for updates, it checks to see if the version number of the newest version is higher or lower, that's it).  But that number does not need to be exposed to the users in any way, unless you wish it to be.  The name does not need to change, you can call every version the same thing and the store doesn't care.